# How to serialize a map with enum keys in declaration order with JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, json-serialization

I have some enum class, let's imagine

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ONE("one"), TWO("two"), THREE("three"), DEFAULT("some value")
    //..
}
```

and Dto class:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"id", "name", "params"})
public Dto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Map<MyEnum, Object> params;
}
```

How can I setup order for **keys** in **params** map? I know that LinkedHashMap can be used to setup order and just add to map in proper order. But! There are cases, when key-value should be added in runtime and it should be added to **params** map not to last link, but inside map. e.g.

```
params = new LinkedHashMap();
params.put(ONE, new String("object1"));
params.put(THREE, new String("object #3"));
```

and than in another place of code we just added

```
params.put(TWO, new Integer(20));
```

and order inside json should be:

```
{
 "id":"123", "name":"some name", 
"params":{"ONE":"object1","TWO":"20","THREE":"object #3"}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest two options that both rely on the fact that Jackson uses a `MapSerializer` to serialize objects of type `Map`.

First, since `enum` types define an implicit natural order based on their declaration order, you can enable your `ObjectMapper`'s `SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS`. The javadoc states,

> Feature that determines whether `java.util.Map` entries are first sorted
>   by key before serialization or not: if enabled, additional sorting
>   step is performed if necessary (not necessary for
>   `java.util.SortedMap`s), if disabled, no additional sorting is needed.

In other words, the enums within your `params` map will first be sorted by their declaration order and only then serialized. **Note that this serialization feature applies to all maps.**

Second, you can initialize `params` as an `EnumMap`. To serialize a `Map`, `MapSerializer` iterates the map's `entrySet()`. The entry set returned by `EnumMap#entrySet()` is ordered by the declaration order of the constants in the corresponding `enum` type. You'd have

```
params = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);
params.put(THREE, new String("object #3"));
params.put(ONE, new String("object1"));
// whatever order
```

and Jackson will serialize them in the order the enum constants are declared.